# Running multiple conditions at once in R

Tags: r

I wrote a code to apply a function to a data frame `input`:

```
    set.seed(1234) 
    n = 5000000
    input <- as.matrix(data.frame(c1 = sample(1:10, n, replace = T), c2 = sample(1:10, n, replace = T), c3 = sample(1:10, n, replace = T), c4 = sample(1:10, n, replace = T)))

    system.time(
    test <- input %>% 
      split(1:nrow(input)) %>% 
      map(~ func1(.x, 2, 2, "test_1")) %>% 
      do.call("rbind", .))

## Here is the function used:

    func1 <- function(dataC, PR, DB, MT){

          c1 <- as.vector(dataC[1])
          c2 <- as.vector(dataC[2])

          c3 <- as.vector(dataC[3])
          c4 <- as.vector(dataC[4])

          newc1 <- -999
          newc2 <- -999

          if(MT=="test_1"){

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 - PR) : (c1 - 1)), y = c((c2 + 1) : (c2 + PR)))
            V1 <- mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * sqrt(2) * DB

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 - 1) : (c1 + 1)), y = c((c2 + 1) : (c2 + PR)))
            V2 <- mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * DB

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 + 1) : (c1 + PR)), y = c((c2 + 1) : (c2 + PR)))
            V3 <- mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * sqrt(2) * DB

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 - PR) : (c1 - 1)), y = c((c2 - 1) : (c2 + 1)))
            V4 <- mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * DB

            V5 <- 0

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 + 1) : (c1 + PR)), y = c((c2 - 1) : (c2 + 1)))
            V6 <- mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * DB

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 - PR) : (c1 - 1)), y = c((c2 - PR) : (c2 - 1)))
            V7 <- mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * sqrt(2) * DB

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 - 1) : (c1 + 1)), y = c((c2 - PR) : (c2 - 1)))
            V8 <- mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * DB

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 + 1) : (c1 + PR)), y = c((c2 - PR) : (c2 - 1)))
            V9 <- mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * sqrt(2) * DB


          } else if(MT=="test_2"){

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 - PR) : (c1 - 1)), y = c((c2 + 1) : (c2 + PR)))
            V1 <- harmonic.mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * sqrt(2) * DB

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 - 1) : (c1 + 1)), y = c((c2 + 1) : (c2 + PR)))
            V2 <- harmonic.mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * DB

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 + 1) : (c1 + PR)), y = c((c2 + 1) : (c2 + PR)))
            V3 <- harmonic.mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * sqrt(2) * DB

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 - PR) : (c1 - 1)), y = c((c2 - 1) : (c2 + 1)))
            V4 <- harmonic.mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * DB

            V5 <- 0

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 + 1) : (c1 + PR)), y = c((c2 - 1) : (c2 + 1)))
            V6 <- harmonic.mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * DB

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 - PR) : (c1 - 1)), y = c((c2 - PR) : (c2 - 1)))
            V7 <- harmonic.mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * sqrt(2) * DB

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 - 1) : (c1 + 1)), y = c((c2 - PR) : (c2 - 1)))
            V8 <- harmonic.mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * DB

            listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 + 1) : (c1 + PR)), y = c((c2 - PR) : (c2 - 1)))
            V9 <- harmonic.mean(sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)) * sqrt(2) * DB

          }

          tot <- sum(c(1/V1, 1/V2, 1/V3, 1/V4, 1/V6, 1/V7, 1/V8, 1/V9), na.rm = TRUE)
          mat_V <- matrix(data = c((1/V1)/tot, (1/V2)/tot, (1/V3)/tot, (1/V4)/tot, V5, 
                                        (1/V6)/tot, (1/V7)/tot, (1/V8)/tot, (1/V9)/tot), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

          while((newc1 == -999 && newc2 == -999) || (c3 == newc1 && c4 == newc2)){

            if(c3 == newc1 && c4 == newc2){
              mat_V[choiceC[1], choiceC[2]] <- NaN
              ## print(mat_V)
            }

            choiceC <- which(mat_V == max(mat_V, na.rm = TRUE), arr.ind = TRUE)
            ## print(choiceC)
            ## If there are several maximum values
            if(nrow(choiceC) > 1){
              choiceC <- choiceC[sample(1:nrow(choiceC), 1), ]
            }

            if(choiceC[1]==1 & choiceC[2]==1){

              newC <- matrix(c(x = c1 - 1, y = c2 + 1), ncol = 2)

            } else if(choiceC[1]==1 & choiceC[2]==2){

              newC <- matrix(c(x = c1, y = c2 + 1), ncol = 2)

            } else if(choiceC[1]==1 & choiceC[2]==3){

              newC <- matrix(c(x = c1 + 1, y = c2 + 1), ncol = 2)

            } else if(choiceC[1]==2 & choiceC[2]==1){

              newC <- matrix(c(x = c1 - 1, y = c2), ncol = 2)

            } else if(choiceC[1]==2 & choiceC[2]==3){

              newC <- matrix(c(x = c1 + 1, y = c2), ncol = 2)

            } else if(choiceC[1]==3 & choiceC[2]==1){

              newC <- matrix(c(x = c1 - 1, y = c2 - 1), ncol = 2)

            } else if(choiceC[1]==3 & choiceC[2]==2){

              newC <- matrix(c(x = c1, y = c2 - 1), ncol = 2)

            } else if(choiceC[1]==3 & choiceC[2]==3){ 

              newC <- matrix(c(x = c1 + 1, y = c2 - 1), ncol = 2)
            }

            newc1 <- as.vector(newC[,1])
            newc2 <- as.vector(newC[,2])

          }

          return(newC)

        }
```

The code works for small datasets but when the data frame contains more than 1 million rows, it is very slow. I think that there are many lines of code repeated in the function (e.g., condition `if else`) which decrease the speed. Are there ways to do all calculations in the function at once? I would really appreciate for any advice.

Comment: I guess you would get more (and faster) answers if you provide a **minimal** reproducible example as code instead of asking to refactor your "production" code. Just my opinion...

Comment: Please add: Which packages are you using? Is it OK to use `data.table` instead of `data.frame`? First impression for optimization: Looping over each row is very inefficient, vectorization would be faster (e. g. `ifelse` instead of `if`)

Comment: While one could inspect your code line by line and try to improve it, it would be much better if you clearly described (in your question) what your function does in words; perhaps then it will become clear that it's better to completely rewrite it rather than to debate on individual things like `ifelse` vs `if`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First a bit of tough love but I strongly encourage you to cover your bases, your code is a concentrate of bad practices and you'll get a huge ROI by spending a bit of time studying vectorisation etc... Consider also posting this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r next time as it is a more appropriate question for there.

**Your bottleneck is not the nested ifs** but the inadequate use of `expand.grid`.

You create in your codes data frames through `expand.grid`, that you improperly call `listC` (they're not lists). Then this costly data.frame is only used for its number of rows, which you get with `dim(listC)[1]` which would be more idiomatic typed `nrow(listC)`.

This value (`dim(listC)[1]`) can only be `PR^2` or `3*PR` in practice, so you could compute those first and just reuse them.

**The nested ifs** can be replaced with nested switch statements, more readable, and
by testing the first choice only once we're also more efficient.

It allows us to see that you forgot one condition in your code. See your improved code below.

When looking at it once it's more tidy, we see that we could actually replace it by simply `newC <- c(c1 - 2 + choice[2], c2 + 2 - choice[1])`.

**Additional observations**

- comment your code, not for us, for you (and then for us when you decide to post a question)
- `c2 <- as.vector(dataC[2])` can be replaced by `c2 <- dataC[[2]]`
- A matrix of 2 columns and one row can be built by `t(c(1,2))` instead of `matrix(c(x = 1, y = 2), ncol = 2)`, but if you're going to use `as.vector` on it in the end, do `c(1,2)` in the first place
- the code could probably be optimized much further

**modified code**

```
func1 <- function(dataC, PR, DB, MT){

  c1 <- dataC[[1]]
  c2 <- dataC[[2]]
  c3 <- dataC[[3]]
  c4 <- dataC[[4]]

  fun  <- if(MT=="test_1") mean else if(MT=="test_2") harmonic.mean
  fun2 <- function(size,mult)
    fun(sample(1:10, size = size, replace = TRUE)) * mult

  pr_sq <- PR^2
  pr_3 <- 3*PR
  sqrt_2_DB <- sqrt(2) * DB
  V1 <- fun2(pr_sq, sqrt_2_DB)
  V2 <- fun2(pr_3, DB)
  V3 <- fun2(pr_sq, sqrt_2_DB)
  V4 <- fun2(pr_3, DB)
  V5 <- 0
  V6 <- fun2(pr_3,  DB)
  V7 <- fun2(pr_sq, sqrt_2_DB)
  V8 <- fun2(pr_3,  DB)
  V9 <- fun2(pr_sq, sqrt_2_DB)

  inv <- 1/c(V1, V2, V3, V4, V6, V7, V8, V9)
  tot <- sum(inv, na.rm = TRUE)
  mat_V <- matrix(data = c(inv[1:4], V5, inv[5:8]) / tot, 
                  nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

  newC <- NULL
  while(is.null(newC) || identical(c(c3,c4), newC)){

    if(identical(c(c3,c4), newC)){
      mat_V[choiceC[1], choiceC[2]] <- NaN
      ## print(mat_V)
    }

    choiceC <- which(mat_V == max(mat_V, na.rm = TRUE), arr.ind = TRUE)
    ## print(choiceC)
    ## If there are several maximum values
    if(nrow(choiceC) > 1){
      choiceC <- choiceC[sample(1:nrow(choiceC), 1), ]
    }

    newC <- c(c1 - 2 + choiceC[2], c2 + 2 - choiceC[1])

    # using switch it would have been
    # newC <- switch(choiceC[1],
    #        `1` = switch(choiceC[2],
    #                     `1` = c(x = c1 - 1, y = c2 + 1),
    #                     `2` = c(x = c1, y = c2 + 1),
    #                     `3` = c(x = c1 + 1, y = c2 + 1)),
    #        `2` = switch(choiceC[2],
    #                     `1` = c(x = c1 - 1, y = c2),
    #                     `2` = c(x = c1, y = c2), # you were missing this one
    #                     `3` = c(x = c1 + 1, y = c2)),
    #        `3` = switch(choiceC[2],
    #                     `1` = c(x = c1 - 1, y = c2 - 1),
    #                     `2` = c(x = c1, y = c2 - 1),
    #                     `3` = c(x = c1 + 1, y = c2 - 1)))
  }
  t(newC)
}
```

Comment: Note I corrected an error, I had left an extra `sqrt(2)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In the case where the data frame `expand.grid` is used for its content (for example, `listC[,1]` and `listC[,2]`), is there a way to replace the data frame `expand.grid` ?

Comment: Well it depends what you want to do, `expand.grid` exists for a reason so you might really need it, on the other hand if `listC == expand.grid(x = c((c1 - PR) : (c1 - 1)), y = c((c2 + 1) : (c2 + PR)))` and you need `listC[,1]`, then you need `c((c2 + 1) : (c2 + PR))[1]`, which is `c2+1`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. `if listC <- expand.grid(x = c((c1 - PR) : (c1 - 1)), y = c((c2 + 1) : (c2 + PR)))` and `listC[,1]` (not only `listC[1,1]`) is used to calculate the mean instead of `sample(1:10, size = dim(listC)[1], replace = TRUE)`, expand.grid is required. Right?

Comment: I've tested the function with modifications but it's still very long.

Comment: I think you should post your function on code review, and explain what you want to do. It's easier to code efficiently from there than iterate on code that approximates your real function